# Creating folder in internal memory root

Tags: android

I want to create a folder in Internal storage root but NOT IN data/data.
In my favorite path, except data/data, that user can see that in File Manager. What should I do?

I try many things like this:

```js
String path = "my folder"+File.separator+"gallery";
    File directory = new File(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file
```

Try using the above code

Comment: i want a folder in root or somewhere to put my images in it directly by file manager @Pallav